# gsub does not replace character properly in gawk

Tags: awk, gsub, gawk

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
gsub(/'/, "&apos;", name)
gsub(/</, "&lt;", name)
gsub(/>/, "&gt;", name)
gsub(/&/, "&amp;", name)
```

I'd like to replace the 4 characters: ' < > & but it's not working the way I'd like, example: I'd like to replace `<` to `&lt;`and it gives me this: `<lt;`

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` is a special character to `gsub` (and `sub` and `gensub`).
It stands for the matched substring in the replacement string.
To get a literal `&` in the replacement string, put two backslashes before it: `\\&`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions

Comment: I should have thought about it as I've already tried with one backslash :)